# Few issues in voting

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
<?php
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';
    include_once 'index_header.php';
    $article_id = $_GET['id'];
    $counter = 0;
    // Select article from db
        $sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = '$article_id'");
          if ($sql){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
            $select_title = $row['title'];
            $Select_article = $row['article'];
            }}

    if(isset($_POST['downvote'])){
    $counter = $counter - 1;

    }
    if(isset($_POST['upvote'])){
        $counter = $counter + 1;
        if($counter<=1){
    $insert_query = $con->query("INSERT INTO votes(vote_count,post_id) VALUES(1,'$article_id')");
        }
    }

    $selet_votes = $con->query("SELECT sum(vote_count) AS vote_count_sum FROM votes WHERE post_id= '$article_id'");
      if ($selet_votes){
      $row_votes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selet_votes);
      $votes = $row_votes['vote_count_sum'];
    }
    else {
        $votes = "0";
    }
    if (empty($votes)){
        $votes = "0";
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function switchImg() {
                if ($('#upvote').css('display') == 'none') {
                    $('#upvote').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#upvote_clicked').css('display', 'none');

                    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
                    var url = "post.php";
                    var upvote = document.getElementById("upvote").value;
                    hr.open("POST", url, true);
                    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
                    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
                    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                                var return_data = hr.responseText;
                                document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = return_data;
                            }
                        }
                        // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
                    hr.send(upvote); // Actually execute the request
                } else {
                    $('#upvote').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#upvote_clicked').css('display', 'block');

                }
            }
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function switchImgdown() {
                if ($('#downvote').css('display') == 'none') {
                    $('#downvote').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#downvote_clicked').css('display', 'none');
                } else {
                    $('#downvote').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#downvote_clicked').css('display', 'block');
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function switchImgdown() {
                if ($('#downvote').css('display') == 'none') {
                    $('#downvote').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#downvote_clicked').css('display', 'none');
                } else {
                    $('#downvote').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#downvote_clicked').css('display', 'block');
                }
            }
        </script>

        <title>
            <?php echo $select_title; ?>
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="rating">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <div class="upvote-div">
                        <input type="image" name="upvote" id="upvote" value="1" onclick="switchImg()" src="images/up.png" />
                        <input type="image" name="upvote_clicked" id="upvote_clicked" value="-1" style="display:none" onclick="switchImg()" src="images/up_clicked.png" />
                    </div>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <div id="counter">
                        <?php
    echo $votes;
    ?>
                    </div>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <div class="downvote-div">
                        <input type="image" name="downvote" id="downvote" value="-1" onclick="switchImgdown()" src="images/down.png" />
                        <input type="image" name="dowvote_clicked" id="downvote_clicked" value="1" style="display:none" onclick="switchImgdown()" src="images/down_clicked.png" />
                    </div>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <p>
                <h2><?php echo $select_title; ?></h2></p>
            <?php echo $Select_article; ?>

        </div>
    </body>

    </html>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['upvote'])){
    $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO votes(vote_count,post_id) VALUES (1,'$article_id')");

        echo "thanks for voting";
    }
    ?>
```

Here's my `post.php` I have two issues:

The main one is that when I click vote, I get `undefined index $article id on line 6`. Initially when I wrote the script, i made ajax url `vote.php`, when i saw the error, i thought that `article_id` wasn't passed to `vote.php` so I put all the action on the same page and strangely, I still get the same problem.

My voting system is like stackoverflow, upvote, downvote and a counter in the middle, but I can't make ajax work. If I post using forms, it doesn't work.

Comment: So many things wrong here: you don't pass in any `id` in the URL; your code allows for SQL injection because you don't escape or filter anything and don't use parametrized queries; HTML, PHP, SQL, Javascript, all in a single file - my eyes....

No wonder you have issues with this script. It's hard to visualize it properly.

Comment: I tell you in an answer, but I'm curious why you use jQuery but your AJAX call is pure javascript. With jQuery AJAX you will obtain compatibility and better readability.

Comment: @AlexanderMP me too, but I try to solve the main problem. We are not here to teach someone how to code. However, with my answer the problem will solve.

Comment: @AlexanderMP about sql injection, I will surely fix it, when I fix this issue, i know about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not passing the correct parameters in AJAX call. You have this:

```
 var upvote = document.getElementById("upvote").value;
 hr.send(upvote); // Actually execute the request
```

So you are sending only a number, not a complete querystring parameters. You need to make that:

```
 var parameters = "id=".$yourId."&upvote=true&downvote=false";
 hr.send(parameters);
```

This is a POST AJAX call, and you are getting the id by GET. So you need to change the method too (in line 6):

```
 $article_id = $_POST['id'];
```

Sending that parameters by POST and reading it with `$_POST` you can solve the problem.

Comment: about `$_post['id']` i cant do that, the reason being is that my index.php looks like http://pastebin.com/R6rUdF9x and i cant get id to post.php unless i use get

Comment: If you need to use GET mandatorily you need to pass the URL to AJAX with that parameter: `var url = "post.php?id=YOURID";`

Comment: upvote now isn't working http://pastebin.com/PgznZLT6 might be a small bug somewhere please could u tell me what doing wrong still?

Comment: This will not work: `var url =  "post.php?id=$article_id";`. It's javascript not php!! You need to `var url =  "post.php?id=<?php echo $article_id;?>";`

Comment: The same here : `var parameters = "id=".$article_id."&upvote=true&downvote=false";`

Comment: Don't limit yourself to copy and paste the code. Understand it and improve it.

Comment: Do you have errors in console? Tell me more information, I haven't got a crystal ball. You are not getting the `document.getElementById("upvote").value`  in nowhere.

Comment: post.php?id=2:129 Uncaught ReferenceError: switchImg is not definedonclick @ post.php?id=2:129

Comment: You have errors in your rendered result. Maybe typos mistake. Please, share your complete code.

Comment: Your javascript crash here: `var parameters = "id=".<?php echo $article_id; ?>."&upvote=true&downvote=false";`. You need to `var parameters = "id=<?php echo $article_id; ?>&upvote=true&downvote=false";`. Take care with the upvote and downvote parameters, you are using `isset()` in the PHP. You must to make some adjusts here to match the php code with the javascript code. Just put a little of logic here.

Comment: do i really need to send `upvote=true&downvote=false`? I mean my ajax is already placed in a function that won't be called unless upvote is true, so why send it again as a parameter?

Comment: You'll get in PHP `$_POST['downvote']` and `$_POST['upvote']`. These are two parameters that you need to pass. I don't know how, you must know if the parameters can reach the php code after ajax call. If it's working before, let it as what you was having in the past. If you still get problems give me some time, I will go to eat right now.